# Permutation groups of S_3

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

The question I have is:
Let $S_3 = [1,2,3]$. Give an example of two permutations $\alpha, \beta$ in  $S_3$ for which $(\alpha\beta)^2 \neq \alpha^2\beta^2$.

This is my answer:
Let $\alpha = (123), \beta=(13)$. Therefore, $(\alpha\beta)^2 = (132)^2$ and $\alpha^2\beta^2 = (12)^2(13)^2 = 1$.

Does this make sense? I'm really struggling with understanding the mapping of permutation groups.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Consider the order of elements. Of course, transpositions have order $2$, but $(123)$ and its square have order $3$. So you should add that $(132)^2=(123)\neq 1$.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Thank you for clearing it up for me.

Comment: You seem to have mixed up some of the computations.

Comment: Did you mean to write $\alpha = (12)$?